# Unusual Lighting Effects - Random Polygons Coloured

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, lighting, normals

I am working on creating an object loader for use with iOS, I have managed to load the vertices, normals and face data from and OBJ file, and then place this data into arrays for reconstructing the object. But I have come across an issue with the lighting, at the bottom is a video from the simulation of my program - this is with the lighting in the following position:

```
CGFloat position[] = { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
```

This is specified in both the render method each frame and the setup view method which is called once at setup.

Various other lighting details are here, these are called once during setup:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
CGFloat ambientLight[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
CGFloat diffuseLight[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0, 1.0f };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
CGFloat position[] = { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
```

The video of the issue can be found here:

http://youtu.be/dXm4wqzvO5c

Thanks,

Paul

[EDIT]

for further info normals are also supplied by the following code, they are currently in a large normals array or XYZ XYZ XYZ etc...

```
// FACE SHADING
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 3, normals);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*numOfFaces); 
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now feel incredibly stupid... All part of being a student programmer I guess. I will leave an answer to this so if anyone else gets this problem they can solve it too! The mistake was simply down to a typo:

```
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 3, normals);
```

Should have read

```
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
```

The second argument being the STRIDE which is only used if the array contains other values e.g. Vert Coords / Normals / Texture Coords. As mine are in single arrays the stride between the values should be 0.